# How do we know that a tilted distribution $\frac{d \overline{\mathbb{P}}}{d \mathbb{P}} = \frac{g(X)}{E(g(X)}$ is still a valid distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, terminology

My lecture notes on Measure Theory briefly reference the idea of tilting a probability distribution but do not explore the topic in any particular depth.

**Background**

My notes say the following:

> Tilting: Consider the measure space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and the non-negative measurable function $g$ such that $E(g(X)) < \infty $. Then we can define a new measure $\overline{\mathbb{P}}$ where we define the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d \overline{\mathbb{P}}}{d \mathbb{P}} = \frac{g(X)}{E(g(X)}$.
>
> The distribution of $X$ under this new measure $\overline{\mathbb{P}}$ is biased by the function $g$.

**Question**

The Radon-Nikodym Theorem tells us that we need both measures to be sigma finite and that $\overline{\mathbb{P}} << \mathbb{P}$ (absolute continuity). How do we know that such a probability measure exists satisfying these conditions?

I would be grateful for any contributions here to clarify this particular concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just define
$$
\overline{P}(A):=\int_A g(x) d P(x) / E[g].
$$
No need for any fancy Radon Nikodym theorems.

If you want to really use it, note that since $g$ is integrable, it vanishes outside of a $\sigma$ finite set (why?!).

Comment: This follows from standard properties of the Lebesgue integral. Is the main issue that it is a measure or a probability measure?